# .find_all to find if the user input matches any of the values (written in an array)

Tags: ruby

So the question is asking me to write a code that will search the hash key for any values that matches a number (the number is input by the user).

The first hash is made up of two key while the value is an array. And the second hash is made up of 5 keys while the value is an array.

My question is mainly regarding `.find_all`. 
I am basically asked to search the hash to see if the number the user wants to investigate is in the hash. 
Please help!

```
puts "give me a number you want information about:"
number_info= gets.chomp 
puts "Using only the first hash:"
if first_hash[random_numbers].find_all { |e| e== number_info }
puts "the number #{number_info} shows up #{random_numbers.count(e)} 
time(s) in the randomly generated numbers"
elsif first_hash[user_input].find_all { |e| e==number_info }
puts "the number #{number_info} was provided #{user_input.count(e)} 
time(s)by the user"
elsif first_hash[random_numbers].find_all { |e| e!= number_info }
puts "the number #{number_info} does not show up in the randomly 
generated numbers"
elsif first_hash [user_input].find_all { |e| e!=number_info }
puts "the number #{number_info} was not provided by the user 
earlier"
end
```

these are the hashes in case you get confused...

```
rand_1= rand(12..21)
rand_2= rand(12..21)
rand_3= rand(12..21)
rand_4= rand(12..21)
rand_5= rand(12..21)


puts "Please provide five integer values between 12 and 21, both 
inclusive:
what's number 1?" 
number_1 =gets.chomp

puts "What's number 2?"
number_2 =gets.chomp

puts "What's number 3?"
number_3 =gets.chomp

puts "what's number 4?"
number_4 =gets.chomp

puts "What's number 5?"
number_5 =gets.chomp
```

**first hash**

```
first_hash={
  random_numbers: [rand_1, rand_2, rand_3, rand_4, rand_5],
  user_input: [number_1, number_2, number_3, number_4, number_5]

}

user_input= [number_1, number_2, number_3, number_4, number_5]
random_numbers= [rand_1, rand_2, rand_3, rand_4, rand_5]
```

**second hash**

```
second_hash= {
  number_1: [user_input.count(number_1), 
    random_numbers.count(number_1)], 

  number_2: 
[user_input.count(number_2),random_numbers.count(number_2)],

  number_3: [user_input.count(number_3), 
  random_numbers.count(number_3)],

  number_4: 
[user_input.count(number_4),random_numbers.count(number_4)],

  number_5: [user_input.count(number_5), 
random_numbers.count(number_5)]
}
```

Comment: "Please help!" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Also, please make sure that you post a [mre]. Does it really require over 50 lines to create a *minimal* code example that accurately reproduces your problem? Unfortunately, you didn't actually state what your problem is, but I would guess that it does not require more than three lines to reproduce.